# Getting error while using watson_developer_cloud in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ibm-watson

I am trying to use Watson Developer in my Jupyter Notebook, but for some reason I am getting error like this.

```
  This is the import part: 
  import json 
  from watson_developer_cloud import AlchemyLanguageV1
```

After this I am getting error like this:

```
       No module named 'watson_developer_cloud'
```

I installed Watson Developer cloud using command shell and ANACONDA prompt.  This is the command which I used and it installed successfully.

```
             pip install -I watson-developer-cloud==1.0.0
```

Do I need to configure any thing to avoid this error in my Jupyter Notebook while importing Watson Developer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few issues here.

1. The install you can use is:

```
pip install --upgrade watson-developer-cloud
```

The current version as of writing this answer is `2.0.1`, not version 1.0

2. Alchemy no longer exists. You should be using NLU instead. There is sample code contained within the SDK.

```
from watson_developer_cloud import NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1
from watson_developer_cloud.natural_language_understanding_v1 import Features, EntitiesOptions, KeywordsOptions

nlu = NaturalLanguageUnderstandingV1(
    version='2017-02-27',
    username='USERNAME',
    password='PASSWORD')

features = Features(entities=EntitiesOptions(), keywords=KeywordsOptions())

response = nlu.analyze(language='en',
    text='The goal is not to be perfect by the end, the goal is to be better today. - Simon Sinek',
    features=features)

print(response)
```

You can view the SDK examples here: https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/python-sdk/blob/master/examples

Comment: Thank You @Simon for the help and information, however I am getting error while running this, I tried to run in the same way as you have mentioned:  I am getting this error     " AttributeError: 'Features' object has no attribute 'get_result'" .